# Alternative for h:selectManyMenu

Tags: jsf-2

I'm using a `h:selectManyMenu`, but it doesn't render correctly in Chrome (12), Firefox (5) or Internet Explorer (8). The `h:selectOneMenu` works fine but it doesn't allow the selection of multiple values, obviously. Does anybody know an alternative? I'm using RichFaces, but the `rich:select` component doesn't allow multiple values either.

update:
The rendering issues are explained here: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-multiple-select-dropdown-box-example/). The main problem is that there's no drop-down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just forget about “h:selectManyMenu” tag, there is really no reason to use it. The “h:selectManyListbox” tag is a good alternative.

---

also with any manymenu-s in the xhtml page use converter, because many menus0 not correctly understand if your value is double or long and itmes value also long or double ..

just add

```
 <f:convertNumber/>

  <p:selectManyMenu id="companyId" value="#{SearchBean.companyIdList}" style="height:120px;">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{SearchBean.companyList}"/>                             
                                <f:convertNumber/>
                                <p:ajax update="data:modelId" event="change"/>    
                                <p:ajax event="unselect" update="data:modelId"/>
                            </p:selectManyMenu>
```

Comment: I was using a `h:selectManyListbox` until I'd find a solution, but it does the job.